# "At least one invalid signature was encountered." in all Ubuntu Docker images in macOS

Tags: macos, ubuntu, docker

I'd expect this command to run without error:

`docker run --rm ubuntu:focal apt-get update`

however, I get instead:

```
Get:1 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal InRelease [265 kB]
Err:1 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal InRelease
  At least one invalid signature was encountered.
Get:2 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-updates InRelease [114 kB]
Err:2 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-updates InRelease
  At least one invalid signature was encountered.
Get:3 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-backports InRelease [108 kB]
Err:3 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-backports InRelease
  At least one invalid signature was encountered.
Get:4 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-security InRelease [114 kB]
Err:4 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-security InRelease
  At least one invalid signature was encountered.
Reading package lists...
W: GPG error: http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal InRelease: At least one invalid signature was encountered.
E: The repository 'http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal InRelease' is not signed.
W: GPG error: http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-updates InRelease: At least one invalid signature was encountered.
E: The repository 'http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-updates InRelease' is not signed.
W: GPG error: http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-backports InRelease: At least one invalid signature was encountered.
E: The repository 'http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-backports InRelease' is not signed.
W: GPG error: http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-security InRelease: At least one invalid signature was encountered.
E: The repository 'http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-security InRelease' is not signed.
```

It doesn't matter which release tag I substiute, they all fail.

docker version outputs:

```
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:           23.0.5
 API version:       1.42
 Go version:        go1.20.3
 Git commit:        bc4487a59e
 Built:             Wed Apr 26 14:46:06 2023
 OS/Arch:           darwin/arm64
 Context:           default

Server: Docker Desktop 4.19.0 (106363)
 Engine:
  Version:          23.0.5
  API version:      1.42 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.19.8
  Git commit:       94d3ad6
  Built:            Wed Apr 26 16:17:14 2023
  OS/Arch:          linux/arm64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          1.6.20
  GitCommit:        2806fc1057397dbaeefbea0e4e17bddfbd388f38
 runc:
  Version:          1.1.5
  GitCommit:        v1.1.5-0-gf19387a
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.19.0
  GitCommit:        de40ad0
```

I would have expected many people to be affected by this, but I haven't found any other reports on twitter.

**Update:**

I tried the same command on a linux docker host and it worked ok:

```
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:           20.10.23
 API version:       1.41
 Go version:        go1.18.10
 Git commit:        7155243
 Built:             Thu Jan 19 17:45:08 2023
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Context:           default
 Experimental:      true

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          20.10.23
  API version:      1.41 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.18.10
  Git commit:       6051f14
  Built:            Thu Jan 19 17:42:57 2023
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          1.6.16
  GitCommit:        31aa4358a36870b21a992d3ad2bef29e1d693bec
 runc:
  Version:          1.1.4
  GitCommit:        v1.1.4-0-g5fd4c4d
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.19.0
  GitCommit:        de40ad0
```

and it worked ok.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out this question:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62473932/atleast-one-invalid-signature-was-encountered

contained the suggestion I needed.

To wit:

running `docker system prune` cleared up a disk space issue which was contributing to the failure.